# Identify Plant from Sardinia

Tags: identification

The plant is very common on Sardinia. The green finger are most possibly capable to store a lot of humidity.

[image]

Edit: I provide two more images of a single plant. Note the plant is now growing inside. Also Note the triangular shape of the leaf/finger cross section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to identify a plant at this level of height. A close-up would help perhaps. Also, does it blooms White petals with yellow centre?

Comment: I will provide a better pictures once I am at home. I have never seen it bloom until now.

Comment: I'm seeing a trailing succulent. If it grows in Sardiania, it grows in Sicily and Italy, Tunis and Marseilles. Bring a few roots home in your carry-on, in rags or newspaper - with all soil washed off - and grow in cactus mix.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is most likely to be *Carpobrotus edulis* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpobrotus_edulis

It is an invasive species in Sardinia and very common in places. There are efforts underway to remove it https://sardiniaisland.blog/2017/05/17/the-pink-invasion/

I have not found much in the way of reference to *Curio sp.* growing wild in Sardinia, so although similar in appearance to your images it is a less probable answer.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it it does looks like string of bananas *Curio radicans* or *Curio hallianus*

[More information on Wikipedia stub](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curio_radicans)

[Wikipedia stub on Curio hallianus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curio_hallianus)

[On care and more images for String of Bananas](https://leafyplace.com/string-of-bananas-plant/)

[On types, toxicity and more](https://getbusygardening.com/string-of-bananas-care/)